# grid layout not equal button size

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

in the picture below i don't know why (.,0,=) buttons are not equal to the rest buttons (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9).

[image: calculator image]

here is sample of my XML code
for numbers buttons

```
<Button
            android:text="7"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_row="20"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:tag=""
            android:id="@+id/button7"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:background="#646464"
            android:onClick="number"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
            android:layout_rowSpan="5" />
```

and for signs buttons

```
        <Button
            android:text="-"
            android:layout_column="3"
            android:layout_row="32"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"

            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:tag=""
            android:id="@+id/buttonSubtraction"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:background="#646464"
            android:onClick="number"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:layout_rowSpan="4"
            android:layout_rowWeight="4" />
```

(.,0,=) code

```
<Button
            android:text="."
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_row="35"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:tag=""
            android:id="@+id/button."
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:background="#646464"
            android:onClick="number"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
            android:layout_rowSpan="5" />

        <Button
            android:text="0"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_row="35"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:tag=""
            android:id="@+id/button0"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:background="#646464"
            android:onClick="number"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:layout_rowSpan="5" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="="
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:layout_row="35"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="5"
            android:tag=""
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:background="#646464"
            android:onClick="number"
            android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:id="@+id/buttonEq"
            android:layout_rowSpan="5" />
```

the complete XML code

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="0dp"
    android:paddingLeft="0dp"
    android:paddingRight="0dp"
    android:paddingTop="0dp"
    tools:context="com.example.ahmed.calculator.MainActivity"
    android:background="#d4d4d4">

    <GridLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:rowCount="40"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:paddingBottom="0dp"
        android:paddingLeft="0dp"
        android:paddingRight="0dp"
        android:paddingTop="0dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

        <Button
            android:text="7"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_row="20"

            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:tag=""
            android:id="@+id/button7"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:background="#646464"
            android:onClick="number"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
            android:layout_rowSpan="5" />

        <Button
            android:text="8"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_row="20"

            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:tag=""
            android:id="@+id/button8"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:background="#646464"
            android:onClick="number"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:layout_rowSpan="5" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="9"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:layout_row="20"

            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="5"
            android:tag=""
            android:id="@+id/button9"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:background="#646464"
            android:onClick="number"
            android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:layout_rowSpan="5" />

        <Button
            android:text="4"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_row="25"

            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:tag=""
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:background="#646464"
            android:onClick="number"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
            android:layout_rowSpan="5" />

        <Button
            android:text="5"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_row="25"

            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:tag=""
            android:id="@+id/button5"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:background="#646464"
            android:onClick="number"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:layout_rowSpan="5" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="6"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:layout_row="25"

            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="5"
            android:tag=""
            android:id="@+id/button6"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:background="#646464"
            android:onClick="number"
            android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:layout_rowSpan="5" />

        <Button
            android:text="1"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_row="30"

            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:tag=""
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:background="#646464"
            android:onClick="number"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
            android:layout_rowSpan="5" />

        <Button
            android:text="2"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_row="30"

            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:tag=""
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:background="#646464"
            android:onClick="number"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:layout_rowSpan="5" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="3"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:layout_row="30"

            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="5"
            android:tag=""
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:background="#646464"
            android:onClick="number"
            android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_rowSpan="5" />

        <Button
            android:text="."
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_row="35"

            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:tag=""
            android:id="@+id/button."
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:background="#646464"
            android:onClick="number"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
            android:layout_rowSpan="5" />

        <Button
            android:text="0"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_row="35"

            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:tag=""
            android:id="@+id/button0"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:background="#646464"
            android:onClick="number"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:layout_rowSpan="5" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="="
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:layout_row="35"

            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="5"
            android:tag=""
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:background="#646464"
            android:onClick="number"
            android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:id="@+id/buttonEq"
            android:layout_rowSpan="5" />

        <Button
            android:text="CE"
            android:layout_column="3"
            android:layout_row="20"

            android:layout_columnWeight="1"

            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:tag=""
            android:id="@+id/buttonCE"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:background="#646464"
            android:onClick="sign"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:layout_rowSpan="4"
            android:layout_rowWeight="4" />

        <Button
            android:text="÷"
            android:layout_column="3"
            android:layout_row="24"

            android:layout_columnWeight="1"

            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:tag=""
            android:id="@+id/buttonDivision"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:background="#646464"
            android:onClick="sign"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:layout_rowSpan="4"
            android:layout_rowWeight="4" />

        <Button
            android:text="+"
            android:layout_column="3"
            android:layout_row="36"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"

            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:tag=""
            android:id="@+id/buttonSum"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:background="#646464"
            android:onClick="sign"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:layout_rowSpan="4"
            android:layout_rowWeight="4" />

        <Button
            android:text="-"
            android:layout_column="3"
            android:layout_row="32"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"

            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:tag=""
            android:id="@+id/buttonSubtraction"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:background="#646464"
            android:onClick="sign"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:layout_rowSpan="4"
            android:layout_rowWeight="4" />

        <Button
            android:text="÷"
            android:layout_column="3"
            android:layout_row="24"

            android:layout_columnWeight="1"

            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:tag=""
            android:id="@+id/button10"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:background="#646464"
            android:onClick="number"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:layout_rowSpan="4"
            android:layout_rowWeight="4" />

        <Button
            android:text="×"
            android:layout_column="3"
            android:layout_row="28"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"

            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:tag=""
            android:id="@+id/buttonMultiplication"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:background="#646464"
            android:onClick="sign"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:layout_rowSpan="4"
            android:layout_rowWeight="4" />

        <Button
            android:text="÷"
            android:layout_column="3"
            android:layout_row="24"

            android:layout_columnWeight="1"

            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:tag=""
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:background="#646464"
            android:onClick="number"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:layout_rowSpan="4"
            android:layout_rowWeight="4" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_columnSpan="4"
            android:layout_rowSpan="20"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/editText2"
            android:text="123456789"
            android:textSize="60sp"
            android:layout_rowWeight="20" />

    </GridLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: post the complete layout

Comment: i edited the question

Answer (score 0):

try to remove android:layout_gravity="fill" from your number buttons.